# Twilio Programmable Chat Android push notifications are data only

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I've configured Twilio Programmable Chat to send notifications for new chat messages via FCM and it's generally working.

However the push notifications received by the Android app are data-only messages and not notification messages (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options). So in order to display the notification I need to extract the data and trigger a local notification in the `onMessageReceived` handler. Also, and most importantly, the notifications will not show when the app is closed.

Is there a way to configure Twilio Programmable Chat to send notification messages instead of data-only messages?

Comment: I am also facing same problem, @martinl did you find any solution/workaround ?

Comment: Sorry @DevKhadka, I had no luck finding a solution. Just making do with the data-only messages.